# python-xbrl module gives error message: "The xbrl file is empty!"

Tags: python, xml, xbrl

I am quite beginner at Python and programming language, and trying to parse an XBRL file using the python-xbrl module.

I'm following the instruction for this module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-xbrl) to parse `.xml` files

But some `.xml` files give this error message:

> The xbrl file is empty!

The following is my Python code, and `HelloWorld.xml` doesn't give the error message while `Novartis-2002-11-15.xml` does.

---

```
from xbrl import XBRLParser, GAAP, GAAPSerializer

xbrl_parser = XBRLParser()

xbrl1 = xbrl_parser.parse(open("HelloWorld.xml"))

print(xbrl1)

xbrl2 = xbrl_parser.parse(open("Novartis-2002-11-15.xml"))

print(xbrl2)
```

---

Novartis-2002-11-15.xml is downloaded from
https://www.xbrl.org/taxonomy/int/fr/ias/ci/pfs/2002-11-15/samples.htm

Do you have any idea?
Any comment will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document `Novartis-2002-11-15.xml` contains an instance that corresponds to an older (public working draft) version of XBRL. In particular, the root element in this file is the deprecated `group` element. python-xbrl finds it empty because it expects a root `xbrl` element, as specified in the latest [XBRL 2.1 recommendation](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html).

```
<group 
   xmlns='http://www.xbrl.org/2001/instance'
   xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
   xmlns:iso4217='http://www.xbrlSolutions.com/taxonomies/iso4217/2002-06-30'
   xmlns:iascf-pfs='http://www.xbrl.org/taxonomy/int/fr/ias/ci/pfs/2002-11-15'
   xmlns:novartis='http://www.xbrl.org/taxonomy/int/fr/ias/pfs/2002-11-15/Novartis-2002-11-15'
   xsi:schemaLocation='
             http://www.xbrlSolutions.com/taxonomies/iso4217/2002-06-30 http://www.xbrlSolutions.com/taxonomies/iso4217/2002-06-30/iso4217.xsd 
             http://www.xbrl.org/taxonomy/int/fr/ias/ci/pfs/2002-11-15 ias-ci-pfs-2002-11-15-WINDOW.xsd 
             http://www.xbrl.org/taxonomy/int/fr/ias/pfs/2002-11-15/Novartis-2002-11-15 Novartis-2002-11-15.xsd 
   '>
  ...
</group>
```

Also, contexts had a different element name back then (`numericContext`), and duration periods were defined differently:

```
 <numericContext id='Group2001ForPeriod' precision='18' cwa='true'>
     <entity>
        <identifier scheme='http://www.novartis.com/group'>Novartis Group</identifier>
     <segment>

     </segment>
     </entity>
     <period>
        <duration>P1Y</duration>
        <endDate>2001-12-31</endDate>
     </period>
     <unit>
        <measure>iso4217:CHF</measure>
     </unit>
     <scenario><novartis:scenarioType>actual</novartis:scenarioType></scenario>
  </numericContext>
```

In the final recommendation, these elements are called `context`.

I recommend trying to read some real filings submitted to the EDGAR system, as these will be conformant. For example, the latest annual reports can be found [here](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&CIK=&type=10-K&owner=include&count=40&action=getcurrent).